# Is there anyway we can stop the hook from saving it to the collection in feather js?

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I want to create a filter on the before hook on feathers. I want to check if the data contains this parameter then don't save this data on the collection. is it possible o feathers?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting [context.result](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#context-result) in a `before` hook. More details can also be found [in the hooks API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#setting-context-result):

```
app.service('users').hooks({
  before: {
    get: [
      context => {
        // Never call the actual users service
        // just use the authenticated user
        context.result = context.params.user;

        return context;
      }
    ]
  }
});
```